# Getting attribute of a property where the property is from an implemented interface

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, attributes

If I have a host of properties in an interface, but in the example I will just use one as it demonstrates what I am trying to achieve.

```
  interface IFoo
  {
    [Bar()]
    string A { get; set; }
  }
 class Base { }
 class Foo : Base, IFoo
 {
   public string A { get; set; }
 }
```

So when I do this:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
f.A = "Value";
Attribute b = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(f.GetType().GetProperty("A"), typeof(Bar));
```

I was expecting to be able to get the instance of my `Bar` attribute out. Most of this is being done in a generic class and I am using my attributes for a validation model so I can't implicitly cast to an interface then get the attribute of the property in the interface because I never know what type the interface will be or what type will implement it. I need some way of getting the attribute out of my instance of `Base` for example.

```
public void GenericMethod<T>(T instance) where T : Base
{
    //Get my instance of Bar here.
}
```

I hope whatI am trying to do is clear, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the list of all custom attributes `Bar` applied to all properties in type of `instance`:

```
var attibutes = instance.GetType().GetInterfaces()
                    .SelectMany(i => i.GetProperties())
                    .SelectMany(
                        propertyInfo =>
                        propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (BarAttribute), false)
                    );
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: That returns an empty array - the properties on the instance *do not have* the attribute

Comment: @MarcGravell, yeah, I see now, thanks. Updated the post to search through the attributes of interfaces' properties.

Answer (score 0):

The property `Foo.A` *does not have* any attributes. Only `IFoo.A` has the attribute. You would need to use:

```
Attribute b = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(IFoo).GetProperty("A"), ...);
```

The only other thing you can do is explicitly check the interface table via `f.GetType().GetInterfaceMap(typeof(IFoo))`, maybe checking each interface that is in `f.GetType().GetInterfaces()` that has an "A".

Something like (and this is messy):

```
var outerProp = f.GetType().GetProperty("A");
Attribute b = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(outerProp, typeof(BarAttribute));
if (b == null)
{
    var candidates = (from iType in f.GetType().GetInterfaces()
                      let prop = iType.GetProperty("A")
                      where prop != null
                      let map = f.GetType().GetInterfaceMap(iType)
                      let index = Array.IndexOf(map.TargetMethods, outerProp.GetGetMethod())
                      where index >= 0 && map.InterfaceMethods[index] == prop.GetGetMethod()
                      select prop).Distinct().ToArray();
    if (candidates.Length == 1)
    {
        b = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(candidates[0], typeof(BarAttribute));
    }
}
```

What this does is:

- if the original property didn't have the attribute...
- it checks what interfaces the type implements...
- and sees what interface-properties the class-property implements...
- and checks whether there is exactly one...
- and looks for the attribute on that

Comment: I see what you mean - I will try this. What I can't understand is why this becomes so messy when the property I am implementing has an attribute all I want to do is get the attribute out? It's as though the class can't see it's implemented properties I guess?

Comment: @LukeHennerley when you implement an interface, you simply don't inherit the attributes from the interface (this is the case even if you used explicit implementation). You can, however, add *your own* methods that only apply to the public API. Design decision, ultimately.